# Unsightly spacing with Calligra font (Christmas card)

Tags: fonts, kerning, calligraphy

I'm writing my Christmas cards again with LaTeX. Last year I used a commercial font with XeTeX. For this year I was thinking about using Calligra as font, but for some reason the output is not nice looking (for me).

This small example

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,landscape,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}


\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{calligra}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{10mm}
\begin{document}
    \calligra\Huge
    \begin{flushleft}
        Liebe aaaaabbba,
    
        ich wünsche euch frohe Weihnachten aaa
        aaaa  aaaa a aa aa aaa aaaa aaaa aaa aa aaa 
        und hoffe, dass ich euren Geschmack getroffen habe.
        
        Viele Grüße\\
        Euer bbaa
    \end{flushleft}
    
\end{document}
```

will render like this:
[image: output]
I think "Weihnachten" looks like W_eihnachten and the text doesn't look left aligned for me.

Is this normal, or is there some error in my Code? I was thinking about some problem with the ligatures...

Comment: It's the "expected" result, given the metrics of the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space after "W" seems like missing or improper kerning.

EDIT: I added more corrections (and consider this an ugly hack).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,landscape,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}


\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{calligra}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{10mm}
\begin{document}
    \calligra\Huge
    \begin{flushleft}
        Liebe aaaaabbba,

        ich wünsche euch frohe \kern -0.22em W\kern -0.22em eihnachten aaa
        aaaa  aaaa a aa aa aaa aaaa aaaa aaa aa aaa 
        und hoffe, dass ich euren \kern -0.22em Geschmack getroffen habe.

        \hspace*{0em}\kern -0.33em Viele \kern -0.22em Grüße\\            \hspace*{0em}\kern -0.33em Euer bbaa
    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One can see also that the V and the E are horizontally aligned with the "body" of the L (the loop on the lower left is sticking out).

Comment: I already thought about this, but I was hoping that this wouldn't be normal. This way I can't use the font for my christmas cards. I won't correct a font manually for all improper kernings.

Comment: @someonr: That's exactly what many free fonts are lacking: Proper kerning.

Comment: Looking at `callig15.tfm` shows that it has no kerning pair whatsoever.